# Browserify bundle undefined dependency

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm using `browserify` in a `Backbone` project and shimming [owlCarousel](http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel)
because it is not a `commonJS` like module. The `shim` transformation seems to work but not when I really need it.

My `app.js` file looks like:

```
var settingsView = require("./settingsView.js");

new settingsView();
```

and my `settingsView`

```
var app = require("./controllers.js"),
    $ = require("jQuery"),
    Backbone = require("Backbone"),
    owlCarousel = require("owlCarousel");
    Backbone.$ = $;

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: ".settings",

   events: {
    "click .carousel-img": "setBackground",
    "click .palette div": "setTextColor"
   },

   options: {
    singleItem: true,
    pagination: false,
    navigation: true,
    mouseDrag: false
   },

   initialize: function () {
     this.initCarousel();
   },

   initCarousel: function () {
     /* This is causing the problem */
      this.owlCarousel = this.$el.find(".carousel").owlCarousel(this.options);
   }
})
```

where my `package.json`

```
"browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "owlCarousel": "./vendor/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"
   },
   "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
   },
   "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "owlCarousel": {
      "depends": ["jquery:$"]
    }
   }
```

The error it's giving me:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.$el.find(...).owlCarousel is not a function

at runtime. But, if I run `$("div").owlCarousel` in the console after dom ready, it works.

Comment: You're calling `initCarousel` from your view's `initialize` but at that stage nothing is actually rendered yet. Move the call to `initCarousel` to after the view is rendered.

Comment: The view is already in html

Comment: My bad, I figured you just left your `render` function out for brevity.

Comment: My bad i did not specifed it eheh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved doing

```
var app = require("./controllers.js"),
    $ = require("jQuery"),
    Backbone = require("Backbone"),
    owlCarousel = require("owlCarousel");
    Backbone.$ = $;    
    $.fn.owlCarousel = owlCarousel
```